# I would like to add some of the quotes to a new screen called as Favorites

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-layoutbuilder

Please be kind and tell me where do I add the line of code and what logic to follow?

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final alreadySaved = _savedQuotes.contains(context);
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue[600]),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Quotes')),
            body: ListView(
              
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              children: <Widget>[
                
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.blue[200],
                  child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                          'You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.')),
             
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

I am very poor at Dart ,And just starting
[Here is the Scrrenshot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIfZR.png)

I want to add like icon on the left for each of the quotes that will toggle the Favorite on and off

Comment: Do you mean that you want the text to be displayed with quotation marks?

Comment: No I would like to add a button on each of the quotes that will add this quote to a new list called "Fav Quotes"

Comment: I suggest you look into the provider package https://pub.dev/packages/provider